# Where to write down the update infomation when submitting a update in app hub?

Tags: windows-phone-7, app-hub

I just submitting a update version of my app in App Hub.

But what confused me a lot is that all the steps for updating is as same as when I submit a new app.

So I just don't know where to write down the update infomation.

I check the MSDN but found no answer with this, so,er,need help -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Description. What I do is add an extra Text as:

### Ver 1.x (This Version)

- Added this feature
- Added this feature
- Modified this feature

Comment: but it will appear in the description section which doesn't mean to fit this content,right? So Is this just a compromise since there is no place to write down the update infomation? :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it in your app description. Just do something like

```
Your original description about the app

=== Updates 23rd May 2012 ===
 - live tile feature added
 - email and sms alerts even when app closed added
```